# How do I include a remote javascript file in a Greasemonkey script?

Tags: javascript, jquery, greasemonkey

I'm trying to write a Greasemonkey script, and would like to use the jQuery library to do so, but I'm not quite sure how I would include jQuery from a web address to get rolling.

**How would I include jQuery (from Google's web server) into the greasemonkey script** so that I can just go:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  // Greasemonkey stuff here
});
```

I'd prefer to get it from this source:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

**Update:** Thanks for the help, the answers were very informative. I did, however, utilize my GoogleFu a little more and came across this *solution*: http://joanpiedra.com/jquery/greasemonkey/

Works like a charm.. just update the source to google's hosted version of jQuery to complete.

Comment: The link didn't work for me, this did: http://joanpiedra.com/portfolio/jquery-greasemonkey

Answer (score 53, accepted):

The recommended way in recent versions of greasemonkey is to use the @require comment tag.

E.g.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name          Hello jQuery
// @namespace     http://www.example.com/
// @description   jQuery test script
// @include       *
// @require       http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js
// ==/UserScript==
```

**However... be aware that jQuery 1.4.1 and 1.4.2 are incompatible with this method**

Thanks Paul Tarjan, for pointing this out. See [jQuery forum thread](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/importing-jquery-1-4-1-into-greasemonkey-scripts-generates-an-error).

**Also be aware of these @require semantics**

At the time that the user script is installed, Greasemonkey will download and keep a locally cached copy of the remote file that can be read almost instantly. The cached copy is kept in the same folder as your installed user-script. The remote file is not monitored for changes.

Please be aware that, at the time of writing this answer, this @require tag is only read at install-time. If you edit an existing user script to add this tag, it will be ignored. You need to uninstall and re-install your user script to pick up the change.

Comment: Wow, that is an extremely simple solution. That's awesome it caches too! Thank you.

Comment: awesome, complete and great answer.

Comment: Careful, this doesn't work for 1.4.1 or 1.4.2 : http://forum.jquery.com/topic/importing-jquery-1-4-1-into-greasemonkey-scripts-generates-an-error

Comment: The cache feature is great and I always use it on my gs scripts. I use
http://jqueryjs.googlecode.com/files/jquery-1.2.6.pack.js
as its small/packed and most of the time it has what I need.

Comment: @fdrv Try putting a query string on the URL, e.g. add today's date. `http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js?2018-10-08`

Comment: This doesn't work if you're trying to use jsconsole.com to log your userscript's console output, at least with Tampermonkey. You get an error that "couldn't load @require from URL".

Answer (score 12):

From [here](http://www.nabble.com/Loading-jQuery-UI-dialogs-from-GreaseMonkey--td19897312s27240.html):

```
// ==UserScript== 
// @name           jQueryTest 
// @namespace      http://www.example.com/
// @include        * 
// ==/UserScript== 

// Add jQuery 
var GM_JQ = document.createElement('script'); 
GM_JQ.src = 'http://jquery.com/src/jquery-latest.js';
GM_JQ.type = 'text/javascript'; 
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(GM_JQ); 

// Check if jQuery's loaded 
function GM_wait() { 
    if(typeof unsafeWindow.jQuery == 'undefined') 
{ window.setTimeout(GM_wait,100); } 
        else { $ = unsafeWindow.jQuery; letsJQuery(); } 
} 
GM_wait(); 

// All your GM code must be inside this function 
function letsJQuery() { 

    alert($); // check if the dollar (jquery) function works 
    // the next call fails 
    $("<div id='example' class='flora' title='This is my title'>I'm in 
a dialog!</div>").dialog({ 
            buttons: { 
                "Ok": function() { 
                    alert("Ok"); 
                }, 
                "Cancel": function() { 
                    $(this).dialog("close"); 
                } 
            } 
        }); 
}
```

It works perfectly, but you may want to limit the sites it runs on or host the jQuery js file on your own site so as not to steal their bandwidth.

Comment: haha that's rad that you just posted that too. I just found that link and replaced GM_JQ.src = 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js'; Thank you for contributing!!

Comment: This is not necessary for recent versions of greasemonkey and you can use the @require tag instead.

Comment: A benefit of using this method is that it should work on Chrome, where using @require will not.

Comment: it doesnt work if i need load script from http for https

Answer (score 6):

You could try dynamically creating a script element:

```
var script = document.createElement("script");
script.src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js";
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
```

You may need to delay for a bit while the script loads (setTimeout?)

Comment: it doesnt work if i need load script from http for https

Answer (score 2):

Based on [Chris's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/779967/2205911), I adjust to my own needs like following.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @description require http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.jss
// @name         Baidu Mask
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  try to take over the world!
// @author       You
// @match        https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/cn/opensource/os-cn-greasemonkey/index.html
// @match        *://www.baidu.com/*
// @match        *://baike.baidu.com/*
// @match        *://zhidao.baidu.com/*
// @match        *://www.weather.com.cn/*
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

(function () {
    'use strict';

    // Your code here...

    var $j;

    function GM_wait() {
        if (typeof jQuery === 'undefined') {
            window.setTimeout(GM_wait, 100);
        }
        else {
            $j = jQuery.noConflict();
            doJob();
        }
    }

    function loadJquery() {
        // Check if jQuery's loaded

        if (typeof jQuery === 'undefined') {
            // Add jQuery
            var GM_JQ = document.createElement('script');
            GM_JQ.src = 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js';
            GM_JQ.type = 'text/javascript';
            GM_JQ.id = 'jquery-lyz';
            document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(GM_JQ);
            GM_wait();
        } else {
            doJob();
        }
    }

    loadJquery();


    function doJob() {
        if (typeof $j === 'undefined') {
            $j = $;
        }

        var url_arr = [
            {'name': "baidu", 'value': "www.baidu.com"},
            {'name': "baike", 'value': "baike.baidu.com"},
            {'name': "zhidao", 'value': "zhidao.baidu.com"},
            {'name': "weather", 'value': "http://www.weather.com.cn"},
        ];
        var url = location.href;
        var siteObj = {};
        $j(url_arr).each(function (i, item) {
            if (url.indexOf(item.value) > -1) {
                siteObj = item;
                return false;
            }
        });

        var delay_arr = [];
        var timerCount = 1;

        function hideTimer() {
            timerCount++;
            if (timerCount > 20) {
                return;
            }
            delay_arr = $j.grep(delay_arr, function (_selector, i) {
                var $ele = $j(_selector);
                var visible = $ele.is(':visible');
                console.log($ele, visible);
                if (visible) {
                    $ele.hide();
                    return false;
                }


                return true; // keep the element in the array
            });
            if (delay_arr.length > 0) {
                setTimeout(hideTimer, 500);
            }
        }

        setTimeout(hideTimer, 500);
        var $frms;
        switch (siteObj.name) {
            case 'baidu':
                $j('#content_right').hide();
                break;
            case 'baike':
                $j('.topA, .lemmaWgt-promotion-slide, .union-content, .right-ad, .lemmaWgt-promotion-vbaike, .nav-menu').hide();
                delay_arr.push('#side_box_unionAd');
                break;
            case 'zhidao':
                $j('.widget-new-graphic, #union-asplu, .jump-top-box').hide();
                delay_arr.push('.wgt-daily');
                delay_arr.push('.shop-entrance');
                delay_arr.push('.cms-slide');
                delay_arr.push('.nav-menu');
                $frms = $j('iframe');
                $frms.hide();
                break;
            case 'weather':
                $j('.right, .hdImgs, .tq_zx, #di_tan, #zu_dui').hide();
                //delay_arr.push('.wgt-daily');
                $frms = $j('iframe');
                $frms.hide();
                break;
        }
    }

})();
```

My script need to work on different sites, while some has jquery included and some not, so I have to test out. **The "require" way not work here**.