# Any working Greasemonkey script with Jquery that works in Google Chrome?

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, greasemonkey

Do you have any link\example of Greasemonkey script with Jquery that works in Google Chrome?

Comment: If you're looking for some close-to-home examples, there are quite a few for SO specifically: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5188/what-third-party-tools-exist-to-use-with-stackoverflow

Comment: @Nick actually, i've developed one of those script :).

Comment: @systempuntoout - Which one? I'm using modified versions of a the rep tracker and comment reply (optimized heavily/chrome specific now)...like the rest of SO as it is though :)

Comment: @Nick this one.. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47162/save-question-to-delicious-greasemonkey-script. I'm interested to make it work in chrome too but i'm not finding any helpful example.

Comment: @systempuntoout - Check this out: http://userscripts.org/scripts/review/68252

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/779739/how-do-i-include-a-remote-javascript-file-in-a-greasemonkey-script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can view the source for the [Add reply-to links to comments script](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38600/script-to-add-reply-links-to-comments), it can be [found here](http://userscripts.org/scripts/review/68252).  It runs in Chrome using jQuery and is *very* handy...it also includes [links to the same question on meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38600/script-to-add-reply-links-to-comments), that follow the comment trail on the tweaks needed to get it running in both Chrome & Firefox :)

Comment: @systempuntoout - Nice! I'm not a delicious user, but looks clean :)

Answer (score 5):

I wrote [an example which you can find here](http://gist.github.com/437513). The main difference from the example provided by Nick is that my example will add jQuery to a page that does not already have it.